# Get `Type` for Array of Type at Runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a variable `prop` of type `PropertyInfo`.

I want to create a `Type` variable which is an array of the `prop.PropertyType`.

For normal generic types I can do `typeof(myType<>).MakeGenericType(prop.PropertyType)` but arrays aren't generics.

The best I've been able to come up with so far is:

```cs
Array.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, 0).GetType()
```

But this is really inelligant, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Type.MakeArrayType()` to do this:

```
var arrayType = prop.PropertyType.MakeArrayType();
```